What's the point of low capacitance capacitors in circuits?
Sometimes I see small capacitors, on the order of 1-2 µF in parallel to loads on DC circuits, like this:

What purpose do these serve?
Related but not a duplicate of Sprinkle switching circuits liberally with small capacitors?. That question is about how to use such capacitors when creating a circuit, while mine is about why.

It is for stabilizing the regulator as well as decoupling low frequency noise. On some old regulators you also needed to provide an output cap with a certain ESR, also for stability purposes.

It may be a matter of opinion, but I wouldn't consider 1μF as a low capacity capacitor.

The smallest value MLCC capacitor Digikey carries is less than 0.1pF, more than 10,000,000 times smaller than your 1uF.

This is not a DC circuit.

I suggest you do some web searches along the lines of "how does a buck converter work" or "how does a switching power supply work".  This should help your understanding go up a lot.

Are you asking why not a larger capacitor to filter ripple better?  As Lundin alluded to, smaller caps can have smaller series resistance and smaller inductance, so actually better as long as their capacitance is large enough.  Some use-cases call for a big electrolytic in parallel with a smaller capacitor to provide large capacitance but still low impedance for transient response.

That is not small. We use fF for ADCs these days.

The first misconception is that what you have in the picture is not a DC circuit.
It is an AC circuit that works at 1.5 MHz.
Sure it is a DC-DC converter but it switches the inductor to ground at 1.5 MHz to charge the inductor with current and then let it discharge the current into the output capacitor.
The capaitors are bypass caps. They store energy.
They have low inductance and resistance, and are placed right near to a circuit that needs fast energy pulses quickly. Or need to store fast energy pulses quickly. In this case, at 1.5 MHz switching speed of the chip.
The capacitor value, type and placement is chosen so that it can do the job well.
Larger, higher value, other capacitor type, with higher resistance and inductance further away with would be useless to provide large currents quickly.

So the capacitor smooths out the burst of energy from the inductor?

"Burst of energy" is probably not the right way to think of it in this instance.  On the output side, the capacitor gets bursts of current from the inductor, and alternately absorbs them and makes up for their lack, to supply the load with steady current at a steady voltage.

The regulator repeatedly pulses current through L1, delivering energy to it, then stands off while that energy is transferred to C2. The regulator does this as often as necessary to keep C2 "topped up" to whatever output voltage is desired.
These transfers of energy from L1 to C2 are very small, but very frequent, anywhere from tens of thousands of "packets per second" to millions. Contrast this frequency with linear supplies, using bridge rectifiers; the capacitors you find in them have to be much larger, because they are required to maintain a reasonably steady voltage for much longer, "top-up" pulses from the rectifier happening only 100 or 120 times per second.
The input capacitor C1 in the switching supply you showed is to "smooth" voltage at the regulator's input, by acting as a short-term source of current as the load's demands change. However, because current is being drawn from that source in short, frequent pulses, current demand is very short-term, and only a small capacitance is required.
You find small capacitors across the power supplies of many elements in a circuit. There are usually long wires and PCB traces between a power supply and the elements being powered, and those paths have inductance which prevents current in them from changing rapidly. Therefore, any element that switches something rapidly on or off will find that the power supply simply can't keep up with changes in current demand. The result is dips and peaks in voltage at the supply rails, which is bad for two reasons:

The element is messing up its own supply voltage
the element is messing up everybody else's supply voltage

Small capacitors across the supply near each element act as a short-term source of energy, able to respond to that element's fast-changing current demands. This helps mitigate the dips and peaks in supply voltage for the element in question and any nearby potential victims.

In the good old days of analog radios, such capacitors could be necessary to prevent "motorboating," which is low frequency oscillation in the power supply.

Why is that mini capacitance not implemented right into the chassis of the element itself? Wouldn't that make downstream design of circuits much easier/cheaper? Or is it necessary to dimension the capacitance wildly differently depending on how the element is used?

@AnoE Building  a so-called "supply decoupling" capacitor into an IC or other element would be expensive, and would remove the ability to choose an appropriate capacitance yourself. You would require more capacitance across the supply of an IC driving LEDs with PWM, for example, than if that same IC were driving only the inputs of another logic IC, because the LEDs would evoke much larger current transients. There is no one-capacitance-fits-all solution.

@AnoE Very rarely, this is actually done--but only for the very highest-frequency stuff, where the inductance in the traces and bondwires between the capacitor and the die can't be tolerated. You see this in expensive MOSFET modules and integrated RF devices, but only rarely in anything else due to the cost involved. You can't practically fabricate suitable capacitors on the same silicon process used to make the rest of the chip, so attaching them would be a separate step, and then it would make the package larger as well, taking up more board area.

@AnoE Many of the answers to this question apply to capacitors as well as to crystal oscillators, though integrating capacitors is somewhat more practical than integrating a crystal.

@AnoE One final note: You do frequently get integrated capacitors in small switching modules--you know, the little SIP-4 or SIP-8 modules that include an entire switching converter, like Recom's econoline series or Murata's MGJ, MEE, or NCS series. These are essentially potted daughterboards with a number of components on them, so adding capacitors doesn't affect the cost much; some of these modules don't require any external capacitance at all, though it usually doesn't hurt to add some more.
